# Indexing customized text documents in solrj

Tags: solr, solrj

I am trying to parse text document which is in customized format.
The format for this document is as follows:

16:15:32.036 attribute1:text1

16:15:32:042 attribute2:text2
.
.
.
.

So the format is time-stamp attribute:value. I am designing the search application using solrj api. 
My query is how should I go about this?
 Should I index the whole text or should I index line by line?
I am not able to find solrj api for this. I would appreciate if you guide me with the approach you would take.

Comment: What do you want to search on?

Comment: I would like to search on attribute name or attribute value.

Comment: I was thinking of using SolrInputDocument but I will need to parse each document line by line. Can Solr help me in this regards?

Comment: You probably need to clean your data and remove the timestamps before you feed it into Solr. If your input doc is a flat file, then you can preprocess it before using them in your Solr client.

Comment: I cam across [UIMA](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/UIMA+Integration) . Can this be used?